# java - searching value inside a multi dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to search an array and find a certain value, if it exists returns true, and if it doesn't exist returns false.

The array:

```
private String zonaDeInternamento[][][] = {
    {
        {"Livre", "Livre", "Livre", "Livre"},
        {"Livre", "Livre", "Livre", "Livre"},
        {"Livre", "Livre", "Livre", "Livre"},
        {"Livre", "0012", "Livre", "Livre"},
        {"Livre", "Livre", "Livre", "Livre"}
    },
    {
        {"Livre", "0013", "Livre", "Livre"},
        {"Livre", "Livre", "Livre", "Livre"},
        {"Livre", "Livre", "Livre", "Livre"},
        {"Livre", "Livre", "Livre", "Livre"},
        {"Livre", "Livre", "Livre", "Livre"}
    }
};
```

So, If the search finds one of the numbers, it returns true, if it finds "Livre", returns false;

```
public boolean isPacienteInternado(String numeroProcesso) {
    if (isNumeroProcessoValido(numeroProcesso)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < zonaDeInternamento.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < zonaDeInternamento[i].length; j++) {
                for (int h = 0; h < zonaDeInternamento[i][j].length; h++) {
                    if ((zonaDeInternamento[i][j][h].equals(numeroProcesso))) {
                        System.out.println("O paciente com número de processo " + numeroProcesso + " está internado!");
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("O paciente com número de processo " + numeroProcesso + " não está internado!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It keeps returning false, never goes inside the if statement, returns the else message and false. Running debug if ((zonaDeInternamento[i][j][h].equals(numeroProcesso))) returns false when numeroProcesso is 13 or 12. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to iterate all the items before deciding if the item is present or not. Remove the `else` loop inside the nested `for`.

Comment: then only check for one condition in the if statement

Comment: I need this statement 
if (!((zonaDeInternamento[i][j][h].equals(numeroProcesso))))
to be returned as false, and need it to be inside the nested for

Answer (score 1):

You have given return false at the end of the block which is causing the error remove the return false at the bottom.

```
public boolean isPacienteInternado(String numeroProcesso) {
   bool value;
   if (isNumeroProcessoValido(numeroProcesso)) {
      for (int i = 0; i < zonaDeInternamento.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < zonaDeInternamento[i].length; j++) {
             for (int h = 0; h < zonaDeInternamento[i][j].length; h++) {
                 if ((zonaDeInternamento[i][j][h].equals(numeroProcesso))) {
                     System.out.println("O paciente com número de processo " + numeroProcesso + "                 está internado!");
                    bool = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("O paciente com número de processo " + numeroProcesso + " não está internado!");
                    bool = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return bool;
```

}

Comment: I need that return statement, else it gives an error when running

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isPacienteInternado(String numeroProcesso) {
if (isNumeroProcessoValido(numeroProcesso)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < zonaDeInternamento.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < zonaDeInternamento[i].length; j++) {
            for (int h = 0; h < zonaDeInternamento[i][j].length; h++) {
                if ((zonaDeInternamento[i][j][h].equals(numeroProcesso))) {
                    System.out.println("O paciente com número de processo " + numeroProcesso + " está internado!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return false;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking one item in the entire array and if it is not equal to `numeroProcesso` then you are exiting the loop. Instead you need to continue looping until either **1. You found a match** or **2. You iterated over every item in the array.** Instead you want something like this:

```
public boolean isPacienteInternado(String numeroProcesso) {
if (isNumeroProcessoValido(numeroProcesso)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < zonaDeInternamento.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < zonaDeInternamento[i].length; j++) {
            for (int h = 0; h < zonaDeInternamento[i][j].length; h++) {
                if ((zonaDeInternamento[i][j][h].equals(numeroProcesso))) {
                    System.out.println("O paciente com número de processo " + numeroProcesso + " está internado!");
                    return true;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    // let the user know that a match was not found
    System.out.println("Combinar não encontrado");
}
return false;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop makes only one itaration because you return true or false in first step. 
So delete the else statement.

```
if ((zonaDeInternamento[i][j][h].equals(numeroProcesso))) {
   System.out.println("O paciente com número de processo " + numeroProcesso + " está internado!");
   return true;
}
```

Comment: I know that removing the else makes it work, but I need the else statement to print a message.

Comment: So keep your else statement only with System.out.println and remove the return statement from here.